# WPF - Data Grid inside pop up does not show its contents

Tags: wpf, datagrid, popup

I have a pop up which contains a data grid. If I divide the data grid into columns, then it shows the columns in the data grid and there is no issue. But when I include some content in the rows in the data grid, then those contents are not visible.

```
<Popup  Name="myPopUp"
            Placement="MousePoint"
            AllowsTransparency="False" 
            PopupAnimation="Slide" 
            StaysOpen="False" 
            Height="370"
            Width="350">

          <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="320"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>

                     <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code" Width="160" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
             </Grid>
           </Border>
</Popup>
```

I  am wondering why it is like that. Can someone help ?
Is that the case that a data grid cannot be included in a pop up ?

Comment: If you directly add a control like Button in the DataGrid, it shows. You can try it. Now, how do you add your ItemSource to your DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

To make a popup control visible, you need to set the IsOpen property to true.
For your reference, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/using-xaml-popup-in-wpf/